# dont allow user to kill program started as another user using setuid bit

Tags: linux, setuid

i have a binary with below permissions.

`-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root`

so when some user X tries to execute the binary, its runs as root. Moreover, the user is able to kill this process(running as root) from his id using

`kill -9`

Any way to prevent the user from being able to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

The user is able to kill the process is because the process is started with the `Effective UID` of `root` but the `Real UID` of itself. Other users won't be able to kill that process.

You can try to set the SETUID and SETGID bit for `id`:

```
# chmod u+s,g+s $(which id)
```

and then compare the output of:

```
id
```

and

```
sudo id
```

and you'll see the difference.

Also you can try to kill a process, which has SETUID and SETGID bits set and is started by the current user, with `sudo -u SOMEOTHERUSER`. You'll see that it can't be killed.

I guess the point of the SETUID and SETGID bits is not to let root own the process, but just to escalate privilege but leaving the process owned by the executing user. And I doubt that you can change it no matter you like it or not (except from hacking the kernel or so?).